# Need Nested sorting elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch

Sample Result : need to sort this (name will always be constant, only value will change)
{
"sampleJson": { "loop1": {
"userId": "1",
"loop2": {
"loop3": [
{
"name": "hindi",
"value": "abc"
},
{
"name": "telugu",
"value": "xyz"
}
]
}
},
"loop1": {
"userId": "2",
"loop2": {
"loop3": [
{
"name": "hindi",
"value": "def"
},
{
"name": "telugu",
"value": "ghi"
}
]
}
},
"loop1": {
"userId": "1",
"loop2": {
"loop3": [
{
"name": "hindi",
"value": "jkl"
},
{
"name": "telugu",
"value": "mno"
}
]
}
}
}
}

After performing elastic Sorting, result should look like below:

{
"sampleJson": {

```
"loop1": {
  "userId": "1",
  "loop2": {
    "loop3": [
      {
        "name": "hindi",
        "value": "jkl"
      },
      {
        "name": "telugu",
        "value": "mno"
      }
    ]
  }
},
"loop1": {
  "userId": "1",
  "loop2": {
    "loop3": [
      {
        "name": "hindi",
        "value": "abc"
      },
      {
        "name": "telugu",
        "value": "xyz"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

}
}

below Elastic sorting is not working: not sure what is wrong with this. any help that would be great.
{
"from": 0,
"size": 25,
"query": {
"bool": {
"must": [
{
"match": {
"userId": "1"
}
}
]
}
},
"sort": [
{
"sampleJson.loop1.loop2.loop3.value": {
"order":"asc",
"nested": {
"path": "sampleJson",
"filter": {
"terms" : {
"sampleJson.loop1.loop2.loop3.name": [
"telugu"
] }
}
}
}
}
]
}

Comment: on what basis are you performing nested sorting ?

Comment: sort should happen based on the nested loop. i.e., name and value, here name will be constant. value need to be sorted.